# I want to know whether i can open two pipe in one process

Tags: c++, process

i am finishing my c++ assignment, in my child process, i open two pipes, one pipe is used to get stdin and one pipe is used to get stdout, because i want to use my stdin to generate an output and redirect the output to another child process, so i use two pipes, but it always crushes when i use two pipes, i want to know how to correct it?

```
pipe(A1toA2);
childpid2 = fork();
if(childpid2 == 0){
    dup2(gentoA1[0],STDIN_FILENO);
    close(gentoA1[1]);
    dup2(A1toA2[1],STDOUT_FILENO);
    close(A1toA2[0]);
    return processA1();
}
```

Comment: Pipes are one-way only. If you want your child process to both read input from and write output to the parent process, then you *need* two pipes. I.e. you need to call `pipe` twice in the parent. If that doesn't work for you, then please ask about that explicitly, and with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help us understand what you're doing. Also please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).